# What is the full wordplay that Joyce employs in "siparioramoci" in Finnegans Wake?

Tags: james-joyce, wordplay, finnegans-wake

What is the full wordplay that Joyce employs in "Siparioramoci" from *Finnegans Wake*
Part III Chapter 2 [468.20]. It arises in the following short paragraph quoted in full. A long winded Jaun/Shaun lecture has ended. This appears to be narrative. I think "their sunder" refers to the twins Shem and Shaun (or perhaps Shaun and Issy).

> Echo, read ending! Siparioramoci! But from the stress of their sunder
> enlivening, ay clasp, deciduously, a nikrokosmikon must come to mike.

From sources at hand and Googling, I can only find the Italian *sipario* for curtain, in particular a [stage curtain](http://www.finwake.com/1024chapter32/prevod468.htm#sipario).

**What is the full wordplay that Joyce employs in "siparioramoci"?**

For the record, "nikrokosmikon" gives us both the Greek [*mikrokosmikon*](http://www.finwake.com/1024chapter32/prevod468.htm#mikrokosmikon): a little small world; as well as [Necronomicon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necronomicon): The Book of the Dead, a.k.a. *Finnegans Wake*. It also involves a Mick/Nick pun.

Comment: [Finnegans Wiki suggests](https://www.finnegansweb.com/wiki/index.php/Page_468) "sunder enliving" = "thunder and lightning" among other ideas

Comment: also in Italian, "siamo pari, ora, amici" means "we're even, now, friends" ("even" in the sense "we're level", "we're square") - or perhaps a similar wordplay with a related meaning